# postgreSQL permission denied when reading from file with \i command

Tags: postgresql

this is my problem:

> ```
> myname@ubuntu:~$ sudo su postgres -c "psql template1"
> Password: 
> psql (9.1.6)
> Type "help" for help.
>
> template1=# \i /create.sql
> /create.sql: Permission denied
> ```

I have this problem even when the file is on the Desktop.
when I copy the text of create.sql and paste it there it works.

using UBUNTU 12.10, postgresql 9.1

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that you've launched `psql` as the user `postgres` and you haven't granted the `postgres` user permission to read the SQL file. You'll need to give it permission. The simplest way is to grant world read rights:

```
chmod a+r create.sql
```

You can change the default permissions assigned to files by altering your `umask`; search for more information. Some programs rather annoyingly ignore the `umask` and set restrictive file permissions anyway, so you always need to know how to grant permissions. See `man chmod` and `man chown`.

BTW, you're using a very convoluted method for launching `psql` as the `postgres` user. This'll do just fine:

```
sudo -u postgres psql template1
```

---

Note that `/create.sql` specifies a file named `create.sql` in root of the file system (`/`). I doubt this is what you intended.

You probably want to specify it as a relative path (without the leading `/`) if it's in your home directory, like:

```
template1=# \i create.sql
```

or if it's on the desktop and you've started `psql` in your home directory:

```
template1=# \i Desktop/create.sql
```

Comment: No, it is there. I didnt mean relative. i put it in the root directory to make the path shorter. but i get the same problem when the file is on my desktop.

Comment: It is not about the path because when the path is wrong the notation is: "No such file or directory"

Comment: @Euler'sformula OK... and what're the permissions on the file? `ls -l create.sql` ?

Comment: the output line is: -rw------- 1 myname myname 2381 Dec  3 13:17 create.sql

Comment: @Euler'sformula OK, so `postgres` doesn't have read permission. See updated answer.

Comment: I am working in windows and that permission granting command didn't work for me

Comment: @SihatAfnan Correct, that's for unix-like operating systems. You need to set the file permissions differently in Windows.

Answer (score 21):

If you work in windows , you just need to pass the entire path wrapped by a single quotation.

```
test-# \i 'D:\\person.sql' --- > note here double backslash not single
```

Comment: Just saved me a bunch of time. Thanks!

Comment: Well worked for me like a charm ! Thank you

Comment: Also, remember to escape the backslashes in the path as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: A better solution is to move the SQL file to the tmp folder if you are on linux!

I ran into this same issue on Linux but the accepted solution was not sufficient in my case. I eventually realized that you need to make sure that EVERY folder in the path has the correct permissions.

For example if the home folder does not have the correct permissions it does not matter what permissions you give a file inside of the SQL folder.

```
/home/username/Documents/SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are facing same issue after putting quote then use forward slash for paths

Answer (score 0):

The problem of permission can be solved by changing the permission of every subdirectory.

```
chmod og+rX /home /home/user
```

This should resolve the problem.

P.S. There could be a risk of security as the permission of these files is set to others for read and execution

Answer (score 0):

It works because you are basically executing the SQL statements as the current user and not reading the file when you copy and paste the entire content of create.sql straight into the terminal. On the other hand, file access permissions are essential in order to use the \i command in psql.

Make sure that the user using the psql command is allowed to access the file /create.sql and that it has the appropriate permissions. The ls -l command can be used to ensure the permissions:

`ls -l /create.sql`

Ensure that the user executing the psql command is able to read the file. Using the chmod command, you can modify these permissions if you find them very restrictive:

`sudo chmod +r /create.sql`

It could also be problematic if the file is kept in a directory with restrictive permissions. Make sure that the necessary permissions are set for the parent directory of /create.sql:

`ls -ld /path/to/parent_directory`

Answer (score 0):

you should move your file to postgres working directory  which is

"/var/lib/postgresq/"

then just execute whatever psql command "postgreSQL permission denied" will no longer be a problem since postgres has all permissions on it's directory