# postgreSQL: permission denied reading a file using \i

Tags: postgresql

I posted this as an answer on the original question posed on
[postgreSQL permission denied when reading from file with \i command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682739/postgresql-permission-denied-when-reading-from-file-with-i-command)
But I now realise I should have posted as a separate question.

My OS is Fedora 21, I have installed PostgreSQL-9.4

I am trying to read a file using the \i command and error message is Permission denied. I have  `chmod a+r` on the file.
On my system there are 3 users [root, damo, postgres] and I have established a group [project] that has 2 members [damo, postgres]. I have used `chgrp`  on all relevant directories which (I believe) should grant permission to user [postgres] to access various files. 
I access pqsql with the user [postgres] but all of my other work is under user [damo]. Within pgsql using the tab to navigate from the command \i stops after

```
    ../../home/damo
```

and I can go no further. This obviously important but I don't know what it means. So I moved the file to that location and it still does not load. This is the output from `ls -l` and `stat`

```
    $ ls -l testScript.sql 
    -rw-r--r--. 1 damo project 76 Nov  5 18:18 testScript.sql

    $ stat testScript.sql 
      File: ‘testScript.sql’
      Size: 76          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
    Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 2623547     Links: 1
    Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    damo)   Gid: ( 1001/ project)
    Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
    Access: 2015-11-05 18:18:06.082928881 +0000
    Modify: 2015-11-05 18:18:06.084928866 +0000
    Change: 2015-11-05 18:25:57.041183384 +0000
    Birth: -
```

Can anyone advance some suggestions?

Comment: \i is a psql command, not a PostgreSQL command. Therefore it will be executed by your psql. Can you access the file from where you are running psql? Do you have read permission on all directories as well?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difference between psql and PostgreSQL?

Comment: I did `chgrp` on all directories above /home/damo/anotherLevel/ but psql doesn't allow me to navigate up to them.So I moved the file to where psql would let me see, `chmod` and still no joy.

Comment: I have now tried `chown postgres testScript.sql` and checked that ownership of the file has changed to postgres. psql still declares permission denied.

Comment: psql is the commandline client, PostgreSQL is the database server. Usually, the server runs on a different account (it's "postgres" on Unix and Linux). Have you tried doing a "su - postgres" from root, and see if you can access this file as user "postgres"? Or can you simply move the file to /tmp and see if it works from there?

Comment: It turns out there was am access setting on my home directory that was stopping further access. A simple `chmod` sorted it out. Thanks for taking the time, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You're on Fedora 21, so you likely have SELinux enabled by default. The `postgres` user probably doesn't have the rights to access the security context `user_home_t`. The security context is shown by your `stat` output. You can include it in `ls` using `ls -lZ`.

The selinux boolean `postgresql_selinux_unconfined_dbadm` looks like what you want for that, per `getsebool -a`.

Check

```
getsebool postgresql_selinux_unconfined_dbadm
```

and if it's `off`, try:

```
setsebool postgresql_selinux_unconfined_dbadm on
```

Also, to determine whether selinux is what's denying access, check the system logs or run the `sealert` tool (SELinux alert browser).

Apart from that, it could well be that one of the directories in the absolute path of the file denies access to your operating system user.

Comment: Thanks for the response. `setsebool` was set to on. 

I used `chmod -R 755 myHomeDirectory` and [postgres] can now access the files. I really need to understand a lot more about how the file permissions are being set on my system.

Comment: @fatherdamo Oh so a missing 'x' bit on a directory probably

Comment: @fatherdamo thank you very much for your feedback. I was stuck for a while now and you got me out of this situation. Best regards.