# \i psql permission denied

Tags: postgresql, psql, permission-denied, sql-scripts

I am trying to run a .sql script that uses postgresql.  I have installed postgresql, and created a database to run the script in however I continuously get permission denied error on the file.  Looking for a solution to issue or workaround to allow me to execute the psql script.

What I have Tried:
BASH:

```
chmod 777 mysqlfile.sql
chown postgres mysqlfile.sql
```

psql commands:

```
\i /path/to/file/mysqlfile.sql
psql -U postgres -d testdb -a -f mysqlfile.sql
```

I have already looked at the following solutions and they did not resolve my issue: [Sol1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736085/run-a-postgresql-sql-file-using-command-line-arguments), [Sol2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682739/postgresql-permission-denied-when-reading-from-file-with-i-command), I used this site as instructions for setting up [postgresql](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-18-04).

Currently I am getting a permission denied error when trying to run the commands I used above, an ideal solution/workaround would be to execute the sql script in postgres on a fresh database.

Comment: Directories have permissions, too. [ what does `cat /path/to/file/mysqlfile.sql` do? ]

Comment: gives me a permission denied error.  Maybe if I create user in postgres as my normal account it will work...

Comment: psql needs two things: 1) connect to the database (this succeeded) 2) read the file (this failed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find a solution after @wildplasser 's comment.  Below I have commands run, in order, for workaround then explanation comes after.

```
cs@cs: sudo -u -i postgres
postgres@cs: psql
(postgres) psql: CREATE DATABASE cs;
(postgres) psql: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE cs TO cs;
(postgres) psql: exit 
postgres@cs: exit
cs@cs: psql
(cs) psql: \i /path/to/file/mysqlfile.sql
```

Why I had to do this way:

When you connect to psql as someone other than postgres it also looks for a database to connect to as that name.  So I had create a database (cs) which is the same name as my local account (cs) or else it would error out.  I also gave myself all permissions on that database.  I was then able to execute the command as expected.

This solution is a little gross.  I'll monitor this thread for a while and if something better comes along I'll gladly switch the answer.

Comment: No `psql` is looking for `-d` database name, `-U` username, `-h` hostname and/or `-p` port number. In the absence of explicit declarations it will fall back to defaults. So if you want to connect to a specific database as a specifier user then use the arguments above to do so. This all spelled out here [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) and here [Key words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS).

Comment: Yes I saw that solution in one of the links from my initial question I posted.